# Covert string to date format for SAS EG 7.1

Tags: sas

i want to convert a string column with date format APR2019 etc into date format Date9.
*Column name is "calendar Year / Month'*

i use the code below

```
input(catx('','01',scan(t1.'Calendar Year / Month'n,1,' '),scan(t1.'Calendar Year / Month'n,2,' ')),Date7.) as Date Format=date9.,
```

it seems to work but gives back all the years as 2020.
for example instead of 01APR2019 i get 01APR2020.

any idea of what i am doing wrong and if you see any better/easier way to make the change?

thanks,

L

Answer (score 0):

Just use an informat and input :

```
date = input(string_date,anydtdte9.) ;
format date date9. ;
```

Comment: i switched date7. to date9. in the parenthesis and it is working now. thanks for the tip anyway :)